# Why is one of the divs not visible in my page?

Tags: html, vue.js, frontend, web-frontend

I am working on a social media like app where I want the profile info section beside the profile image but when I add both divs inside a single div, only the profile image section is visible.

This is how it should look:

[image: community-page]

Here is the template part of the code:

```
<template>
  <v-app id="app" class="mt-0">
    <v-container grid-list-xl>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <ImageInput v-model="avatar" class="avatar">
        <div slot="activator">
          <v-avatar size="250px" v-ripple v-if="!avatar" class="grey lighten-3 mb-3">
            <span>Click to add avatar</span>
          </v-avatar>
          <v-avatar size="150px" v-ripple v-else class="mb-3">
            <img :src="avatar.imageURL" alt="avatar">
          </v-avatar>
        </div>
        <v-slide-x-transition>
          <div v-if="avatar && saved == false">
            <v-btn class="primary" @click="uploadImage" :loading="saving">Save Avatar</v-btn>
          </div>
        </v-slide-x-transition>
        <div class="profile-info">
          <h1>{{ Name }}</h1>
          <div class="stats">Posts: {{ totalPosts }} </div>
          <div class="stats">Followers: {{ followers }}</div>
          <div class="stats">Following: {{ following }}</div>
          <p>{{ bio }}</p>
        </div>
      </ImageInput>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

This is how ImageInput looks:

```
<template>
<div>
    <!-- slot for parent component to activate the file changer -->
    <div @click="launchFilePicker()">
        <slot name="activator"></slot>
    </div>
    <!-- image input: style is set to hidden and assigned a ref so that it can be triggered -->
    <input type="file" ref="file" :name="uploadFieldName" @change="onFileChange(
        $event.target.name, $event.target.files)" style="display:none">
    <!-- error dialog displays any potential error messages -->
    <v-dialog v-model="errorDialog" max-width="300">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-text class="subheading">{{ errorText }}</v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn @click="errorDialog = false" flat>Got it!</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</div>
```

export default {
    name: 'image-input',
    data: () => ({
        errorDialog: null,
        errorText: '',
        uploadFieldName: 'file',
        maxSize: 1024
    }),
    props: {
        // Use "value" to enable using v-model
        value: Object,
    },
    methods: {
        launchFilePicker() {
            this.$refs.file.click();
        },
        onFileChange(fieldName, file) {
            const { maxSize } = this
            let imageFile = file[0]
            if (file.length > 0) {
                let size = imageFile.size / maxSize / maxSize
                if (!imageFile.type.match('image.*')) {
                    // check whether the upload is an image
                    this.errorDialog = true
                    this.errorText = 'Please choose an image file'
                } else if (size > 1) {
                    // check whether the size is greater than the size limit
                    this.errorDialog = true
                    this.errorText = 'Your file is too big! Please select an image under 1MB'
                } else {
                    // Append file into FormData and turn file into image URL
                    let formData = new FormData()
                    let imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageFile)
                    formData.append(fieldName, imageFile)
                    // Emit the FormData and image URL to the parent component
                    this.$emit('input', { formData, imageURL })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Hard to say without seeing `ImageInput`. Is it correct that the `div.profile-info` go into the default slot of `ImageInput`?